# how to fetch main category and nesting there subcategory between them one by one using mysql

Tags: php

I want to display main category and between them show their belonging sub-category. I want to display sub-category those belong to particular main category from database. In my database two different table category and sub-category. Here is my code. Problem is that all things are working but sub-category are repeating again again how to limit them I want display one time a particular sub-category.

```
<div class="product_right">
<h4 class="m_2"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span>Categories</h4>
<?php
$mysqlData = mysql_query("select * from `sub_category` group by `name` desc");
while($mysqlFetchRows = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysqlData))
{
    $mCat = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from `category` where `id`='".$mysqlFetchRows['cid']."'"));
?>
<div class="tab1">
<ul class="place">               
<li class="sort"><?php print $mCat['name'];?></li>
<li class="by"><img src="images/do.png" alt=""></li>
<div class="clearfix"> </div>
</ul>
<div class="single-bottom">            
<a href="#"><p><?php print $mysqlFetchRows['name']?> </p></a>

</div>
</div>  
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: One advice is, find out  categories who do not belongs to any other category they are parent, find out category they do not have sub category they are leaf category, taking any into consideration, you should try getting next level  and then again next level so on. and if it is wordpress / woocommerce, let me know, I have done that and one of answer regarding that is on stack.

Comment: It looks like your code is backwards to what you want to do. You say that you want to do `category and sub-category`, but your outer query is `from \`sub_category\``, and your inner/nested query is `from \`category\``.

Comment: i am not using wordpress cms i am using core php and mysql

Comment: ya i first i am fetching category lis and sub category from sub-category table because sub-category table has whole record of catid and there sub-category

Comment: Use mssqli, mssql is not secure and is deprecated.  Single query.  Select sub.name from category as cat join sub-category as sub on cat.id = sub.cid group by sub.name order by sub.name desc.    on phone, sorry syntax   is bad.   for performance, a single query with results is better then a nested query.  Almost looks like Oscommerce code.

Comment: Kyle Wiering thanks for suggest but its performance be affected always there is another method to improve performance